# In Eclipse, is it possible to store PHP debug configuration on a per project basis?

Tags: php, eclipse

Our team is developing a PHP application and using Eclipse. I'm not very familiar with Eclipse but I have been able to configure debug for different projects (representing different branches of the code) so I can use the debugger.

However if I have 10 projects, I will have 10 debug configurations which is sometimes confusing (for instance, I may mistakenly choose "debug branch 1" while working on branch 2).

If I understand correctly, it is possible to store `Java` launch configuration on per project basis but I haven't find this for `PHP Web Application`. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to the Eclipse PDT forum. See [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1795675/#msg_1795675).

Basically, you need to store the debug configuration in a "shared file" (a terrible name) inside the project. See [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264629) (the example is about a C/C++ project but it works for PHP projects too).